# It feels like there can be more than one correct answer to the way these questions are posed

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, tenses

Can someone tell me if this quiz is credible? Answers and the reasoning behind them would be most helpful in the case that it is credible. My feeling is the questions are posed in an ambiguous way and there may more than one right answer.

EDIT: I narrowed down this post to one question as the moderator suggested.

Here is the question as it is given:

> Choose the correct verb form in brackets for the following sentence:
> Max________(study) English every night.
>
> 1. studies
> 2. studied
> 3. has been studying
> 4. will be studying

My feeling is that, unless there is something inherently wrong with three of the options, the required tense form should be part of the question if I am to choose the correct verb form. So if the question wants an answer that suggests Max's studying is a habit, I should choose the answer that is in the *simple present* form; **studies**. The second option in *simple past* form,**Studied**, suggests a test that has occurred in the past and Max is no longer studying for it, so the question should indicate that or ask for the answer that is in the *simple past*. Option three sounds like it is in the *present perfect progressive* suggesting a test will take place in the future and the studying is ongoing for that purpose. Option four might imply that the test date was just announced and that Max's intention is to form a habit of studying for it.

Are all four options possible?

Comment: Welcome! May I suggest you take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) (although that was specific to an engineering site).

Comment: I can understand some people's frustration, but I need to know if my professor is credible, as I cannot ask this person for help. If it is any consolation to people who want more effort in good faith, I have already been graded. But I reiterate, MY resources for learning are not worthy of faith.

Comment: This is a worthless test. Almost all listed answers to the questions are at least possible and many are perfectly fine *depending on the context*. Question 10, for example, lists four possible answers that are impossible to choose between unless you know the context. @tchrist's answer below sums it up admirably.

Comment: Is this a test which is marked, or an exercise intended to provoke discussion in class?

Comment: This was a graded test, not intended for discussion.

Comment: All four options are correct, each one in their own context. But I am afraid the questions still remains off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not a reasonable test: there are usually many “correct” answers, not just one alone, in those examples.

This is yet another dumb guessing game where the student must pick what the instructor wants them to, not what is right. It does not uniquely reflect actual grammatical English as invariably chosen by native speakers in all possible contexts.

So the test isn’t worth diddly squat.

Comment: I really appreciate you answering when I may have given the impression that I am looking for easy answers.

Comment: Some are rather poor, others clearer. Perhaps 'best' would have been more appropriate than 'correct'.

Comment: @WeatherVane: All the answers in Question 10 are "best" depending on the context, which is absent.

Comment: @Robusto in Q10 as a simple statement devoid of context, 'walk' is IMO the best answer, because the other options *do* need some context. I stand by "the test is rather poor" though.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The fact that you must rely on opinion for a context-free multiple-choice question shows that this test is a failure. A fair test would supply context and anything else needed to ensure a single correct response.

Comment: Not ELU standard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What would you see me do here?

Comment: You know that I'd 'answer' in a 'comment' and (as here) CV the question. I'd like an intermediate, sub-answer format where answers to questions one also close-votes can be offered ['I have voted to close as I consider this question (a) lacks signs of reasonable research, (b) ... but  will explain that .... Please visit the HC before ....'], to help yet discourage inappropriate questions. And here, obviously, 'Is the following correct? (a)' (+ 3 similar questions) would be at highest ELL level. And we've had so many 'Is this test correct?' queries, with the answer 'Find different sources'.